# Getting from Avalon Airport (AVV) to Melbourne CBD

Tags: public-transport, australia, airport-transfer, melbourne, avv

One way to get from Avalon Airport to Melbourne CBD is by [Avalon City Express](https://www.skybus.com.au/avalon-city-express/). It's 24 AUD one way or 46 AUD roundtrip. I was wondering whether there are any other transportation options that are cheaper?

Comment: Did you check [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com) yet?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't show anything cheaper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Other than the Sky Bus (City Express) there's no other means of getting in outside of a taxi.

From [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Melbourne):

> Avalon Airport (AVV IATA) is a mainly domestic airport 55 km
>   south-west of Melbourne in Lara, near Geelong. Although much further
>   than Melbourne Airport, fares from Avalon are sometimes considerably
>   cheaper. The terminals are generally very simple, with just an ATM,
>   car hire desks and baggage carousels. Other facilities include a cafe,
>   bar and a video arcade room. There are several flights in and out of
>   Avalon each day, with many domestic operated by lower-cost airline
>   Jetstar (which also flies to Melbourne Airport) and an AirAsiaX flight
>   to Kuala Lumpur.
>
> SkyBus operates a coach shuttle to Southern Cross Station in
>   Melbourne's City Centre via the outer western suburb of Werribee,
>   meeting every flight arrival and departure. The transfer costs $22
>   one-way for an adult, and $10 for a child (4-14 years). Other than the
>   coach, there is no public transport; Lara Station is 8 km from the
>   terminal, meaning one could ride a bike on the road to/from the
>   airport or catch a taxi, which would cost about $15 to the station. A
>   taxi to the city from the airport could cost upwards of $100.

You could try to hitchhike, but other than that, you're really stuck with the bus.

Comment: The train fare from Lara to Southern Cross is $4.40 (plus Myki deposit if needed), so the cost savings for taxi & train vs the direct bus are minimal.